# Connection refused when trying to set up a simple Client Server system

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I'm getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection
```

whenever I try to start the server in this simple system I have setup. The code is just basically copied from a tutorial in which it ran perfectly, so I can only assume this is some enviormental issue which I am encountering (MAC OSX 10.10.5 / Netbeans)

Here are my classes:

Client:

```
public class Client
{
   public static void main(String [] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
   {
       int number,temp;
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1",1342);
       Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
       System.out.println("Print any number:");
       number = sc.nextInt();
       PrintStream p = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
       p.println(number);
       temp = sc1.nextInt();
       System.out.println(temp);


   }
}
```

Server:

```
public class Server 
{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException{

        int number,temp;
        ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(1342);
        Socket ss= s1.accept();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(ss.getInputStream());
        number=sc.nextInt();

        temp = number*2;

        PrintStream p = new PrintStream(ss.getOutputStream());
        p.println(temp);   
    }
}
```

Does anybody have any ideas on what I am ding wrong, or whats wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happening because you're starting first your client class and then the server.

You should first run the server and afterwards the client.

First you go to your `Server` and do: *Run As > Java Application*

The server starts.

Then, you go to your `Client` and do: *Run As > Java Application*

The client starts and you'll see on your console:

```
Print any number:
```

Comment: Yea, just realised that and then I refreshed this. I'm a complete idiot. Thanks.